# How to get shipping address prestashop

Tags: arrays, prestashop

I created a carrier module with two kind of shipping method, i have a function to get order shipping cost, here i want to get an array of shipping address to validate the zip code,

Here the code of i try,

```
public function getOrderShippingCost($params, $shipping_cost, $package = array())
    {           
                    $postal_code = $package['destination']['postcode'];
                    $country = $package['destination']['country'];
                    $contents_cost = $package['contents_cost'];

                    }
```

running my store in debbug, show me `this Undefined index:` for destination and contents_cost.

How can get all the shipping addres values?

Comment: I do not see in your code where you trying to get and validate ZIPs. Error message just show you that $package array does not contain certain indexes.

Comment: i follow a example where do the same thing and only put these code, im new in prestashop.

Answer (score 1):

You can get shipping address with a method like this :

```
public function loadReceiverAddress($cart) // Cart or order object
 {

  $address = new Address($cart->id_address_delivery);
  $city = $address->city;
  $zip = $address->postcode;
  $country = $address->country;
  $state = State::getNameById($address->id_state);
  $street_no=$address->address1;

  return array($city,$zip,$country,$state,$street_no);
 }
```

You can call this method when you want to get shipping address by cart or order object, this is an example of use :

```
// Create a new Order Object with order id    
$order = new Order((int)Tools::getValue('id_order'));

// Get delivery address details 
list($firstname,$lastname,$company,$phone_mobile,$city,$zip,$country,$state,$street_no,$email)=$this->loadReceiverAddress($order,true);
```